# How would I read the following text into a 2D Array

Tags: java, null, multidimensional-array

Once written to text file the 2D object looks like this:

```
null null -5 160 2 null null
null 75 80 1 75 160 0 null 75 320 1 
null null 155 160 2 null null 
235 0 1 235 80 2 235 160 1 null null
```

the object is in the form

```
elements(x,y,i)
```

So each object makes use of 3 digits.

The problem arises in reading the Integers from the text file as it is mixed with the String from the "null values."
This is what I have so far but it only partially reads the text file.

```
    public void readElements() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("elements.txt");
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(file);


        for (int col = 0; col <rectArr.length; col++){

            if(inp.hasNextLine()) {
                inp.nextLine();
            }

            for(int row = 0; row<rectArr[0].length; row++){
               if(inp.hasNext()) {
                   try {
                       String s = inp.next();
                       Integer.parseInt(s);

                       System.out.println(s);

                       int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
                       int y = Integer.parseInt(inp.next());
                       int i = Integer.parseInt(inp.next());

                       elementsArr[col][row] = new elements(x, y, i);

                   } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

                   }
               }
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: You need to think more carefully about what should happen when there's a `null` in the input.

Comment: What @DavidWallace said, plus: How do you know what _rectArr.length_ is right after reading the file? I wonder if an array is the best design choice here.

Comment: `if (s.trim().equals("null")){ /*do whatever*/ }`

Comment: Thansk @paisanco rectArr.length was the issue

Comment: @yesno I found a solution for you but I need more info. can you tell me what is size of your 2d array? is it 2 by 2 for example?

Comment: @KickButtowski It was a [4][5], but as someone else pointed out my .length seemed to be the problem. Thanks though!!!

Comment: @yesno so u do not wanna help?

Comment: your questions had made me nuts, wanna talk about it?